# Prolog inheritance logic: how to match?

Tags: prolog

I'm just scratching the surface of Prolog... I do kinda feel that what I'm doing is wrong, but I don't know how to make it right :). These are the clauses:

```
game :- boardgame  % game is 'true' if boardgame is true 
                   % this is the thing I feel is not right 
owns(jolene,boardgame)
```

If I query it, I'd like to have that `owns(jolene,game)` is true (since a boardgame is a game as well). It clearly doesn't work like this, but well... how would I make this example work properly?

**-- 2nd iteration:**

```
boardgame(robotrally).
owns(jolene,boardgame(robotrally)).
game(X) :- boardgame(X).
```

But still, jolene doesn't own a game, although she owns a boardgame.

**-- 3rd iteration:**

```
isa(boardgame,game).
owns(jolene,boardgame).
```

query: `isa(X,game),owns(jolene,X).`
seems to be close...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an implicit "is-a" relationship that you haven't taught Prolog about. I think you want to approach it like this:

```
%% owns(Person, Object)
owns(jolene, roborally).

%% is_a(Thing, BroaderClassOfThing)
is_a(roborally, boardgame).
is_a(boardgame, game).

%% owns_a(Person, KindOfThing)
owns_a(Person, Thing) :- owns(Person, Thing).
owns_a(Person, GeneralThing) :- 
   is_a(MoreSpecificThing, GeneralThing), 
   owns_a(Person, MoreSpecificThing).
```

Now you can make your query:

```
?- owns_a(jolene, game)
true.
```

Comment: yeah, was getting close to something like this. Thanks!